# cumsum() in Pandas gives "Memory Error" while creating values based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to populate new column with unique integer values, based on condition from another column. But getting memory error after using `cumsum()`. Is there any other way where i can do this without memory error?

Code:

```
s = df['create?'].cumsum().where(df1['create?'] == 'Yes')
df['new_id'] = df.groupby(s).ngroup()+1
df['new_id'].replace(0,'',inplace=True)
```

Error:

```
lambda y, axis: y.cumsum(axis),
MemoryError
```

Input(small Example):

```
create?
No
No
Yes
No
Yes
Yes
Yes
No
No
No
Yes
```

Expected Output:

```
create? new_id
No  
No  
Yes       1
No  
Yes       2
Yes       3
Yes       4
No  
No  
No  
Yes       5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```py
df.loc[df['create?'] == 'Yes', 'new_id'] = 1
df['new_id'] = df['new_id'].cumsum().fillna('')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   create? new_id
0       No       
1       No       
2      Yes      1
3       No       
4      Yes      2
5      Yes      3
6      Yes      4
7       No       
8       No       
9       No       
10     Yes      5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'create?': ['Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No']})
df['new_id'] = [1 if a == 'Yes' else 0 for a in df['create?']]
df['new_id'] = df['new_id'] * df['new_id'].cumsum()
print(df)

create?  new_id
0     Yes       1
1      No       0
2     Yes       2
3     Yes       3
4      No       0
```